# On NSSavePanel, is there a way to force the “Hide extension” checkbox to show?

Tags: xcode, appkit, nsdocument

I have overridden NSDocument’s `prepareSavePanel(_:)` method to attempt to add a checkbox to allow the user to hide the filename extension when saving.

```
override func prepareSavePanel(_ savePanel: NSSavePanel) -> Bool {
        savePanel.canSelectHiddenExtension = true
        savePanel.isExtensionHidden = false
        return true
}
```

But the checkbox still won’t show on the Save panel.

Comment: "Hide Extension" is now in the pull-down menu.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you so much! Please put your comment as the answer so that I can credit you with the correct answer. This really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hide Extension" is now in  the pull-down menu.

[image]